# mpdf addPage creates blank pages

Tags: php, html, css, mpdf

Hi when I try to use `$mpdf->addPage()` within a for loop , instead of creating a new page with content a blank page is created instead. I want to break the page after a certain condition is reached, then after the new page is created content should be added.  This is a rough idea   of how the code flows..

```
$form = '<html head informatio here >';
          $mpdf->WriteHTML($form);

$form .= '<html body content which is essentiall a nested table >'
          within this section i have a for loop
         for ( $i=0; $i < $rows; $i++ ): 
          $mpdf->WriteHTML($form);  
          at certain points I would do a 
          $mpdf->AddPage();
          endfor; 

$form .= '<html footer information >'

$mpdf->WriteHTML($form);
```

The result is everything gets placed on the last page of the pdf whilst I have about 6 or 7 blank pages. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

```
$form = '<html head informatio here>';
          $mpdf->WriteHTML($form);
$form .= '<html body content which is essentiall a nested table >';

          //within this section i have a for loop//

         for ( $i=0; $i < $rows; $i++ ): 
          $mpdf->WriteHTML($form); 

         // at certain points I would do a //

          //$mpdf->AddPage();

           $form .= '<div style="page-break-after:always"></div>';

           $mpdf->WriteHTML( $form);

          endfor; 

$form .= '<html footer information >';


$mpdf->WriteHTML($form);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the following mpdf dcumentation. I think you need to add a page break manually inside the code.

http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=108

Comment: thanks i will have a look at this.. much appreciated